# Implementing busy wait with a pair of flags

Tags: busy-waiting

I am trying to implement a busy waiting mechanism, using 2 flags. I get a deadlock, but just can't understand why... it looks to me as if it should work...

sorry for the long code, That's the shortest I succeeded to make it.

```
package pckg1;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Buffer b = new Buffer();
    Producer prod = new Producer(b);
    Consumer cons = new Consumer(b);

    cons.start();
    prod.start();
}
}

class Producer extends Thread {
private Buffer buffer;

public Producer(Buffer buffer1) {
    buffer = buffer1;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        while (!buffer.canUpdate)
            ;
        buffer.updateX();
        buffer.canUpdate = false;
        buffer.canUse = true;
    }
}
}

class Consumer extends Thread {
private Buffer buffer;

public Consumer(Buffer buffer1) {
    buffer = buffer1;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        while (!buffer.canUse)
            ;
        buffer.consumeX();
        buffer.canUse = false;
        buffer.canUpdate = true;
    }
}
}

class Buffer {
private int x;
public boolean canUpdate;
public boolean canUse;

public Buffer() {
    x = 0;
    canUpdate = true;
}

public void updateX() {
    x++;
    System.out.println("updated to " + x);

}

public void consumeX() {
    System.out.println("used " + x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that all the logic concerning `Buffer` should go into that class.

Also, accessing (and modifying) the flags must be protected, if 2 or more have access to it. That's why I put `synchronised` to the 2 methods.

```
class Buffer {
private int x;
private boolean canUpdate;
private boolean canUse;

public Buffer() {
    x = 0;
    canUpdate = true;
}

public synchronised void updateX() {
    x++;
    System.out.println("updated to " + x);
    canUpdate = false;
    canUse = true;
}

public synchronised void consumeX() {
    System.out.println("used " + x);
    canUpdate = true;
    canUse = false;
}

    public synchronised boolean canUse() {
        return canUse;
    }
    public synchronised boolean canUpdate() {
        return canUpdate;
    }
}
```

Also, remove the `canUpdate` and `canUse` writes from the `Producer` and `Consumer` classes, and replace the reads (in the conditons) with the methods.

Also, it would be useful to introduce some `Thread.sleep(100)` in the waiting loops.

Comment: Thanks, its different than in C threads I think... there you don't have to sync every variable that is accessed by more than one thread if the logic itself prevents deadlocks (As far as I remember).